# Selecting only what I want to select on Mac

Tags: high-sierra, mouse, trackpad

Selecting text with trackpad or mouse has become super annoying experience - my Mac thinks he knows better than me what I want to select and will extend/shrink the selection to fit some hidden rules.

Sometimes I can not select the specific subset of a word no matter what, the last resort is to hold shift and use arrow keys.

Is there a remedy to this madness?

Comment: What program? MS Office apps have a preference to "select entire word." Which I find incredibly annoying...

Comment: Gosh you are right, this is MS Office madness, sorry my darling! Where do I switch it off??

Comment: it's in Preference > Editing > Select entire word when selecting text.